# firebase hosting problem with Next.js server-side parsing formData

Tags: node.js, firebase, next.js, multer

We're using **Next.js** with **firebase hosting**.
I,m tryng to send a POST a **formData** on **client-side** of next.js, and after that on **server-side** it first needs to **parse formData** from request and then access to its details.

I think the problem is firebase hosting provides serve static assets and serverless functions! So primarily firebase doesn't support parsing formData in node.js envirentment! (I'm not sure about it!)

this is the server-side code:

```
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
import axios from "axios";

const multer = require("multer");
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

const upload = multer({ // Disk Storage option
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
        filename: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
            const uniqueSuffix = `${Date.now()}-${Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)}`;
            const originalExtension = file.mimetype.split('/').pop();
            cb(null, `${file.originalname}-${uniqueSuffix}.${originalExtension}`);
        },
    }),
});


export default async function handler(req: any, res: NextApiResponse) {

    const authorization = req.headers.authorization;

    // Return 401 error in case of an invalid token
    if (!authorization || authorization.trim() === "Bearer") {
        return res.status(401).json("Not Authorized!");
    }


    // Creating a new formData
    const formData = new FormData();


    // Parsing data
    upload.single('image')(req, res, async function (err: any) {

        // Handle errors
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }

        // Add fields to formData
        const fields = req.body;

        for (const key in fields) {
            formData.append(key, fields[key]);
        }

        // Add image
        const uploadedFile = req.file;

        if (uploadedFile) {
            const image = fs.createReadStream(uploadedFile.path);

            formData.append("image", image, {
                contentType: uploadedFile.mimetype
            });
        }


        try {
            const result = await axios.post('https://carbonpath-tviksclt2a-uc.a.run.app/api/v1/products/', formData, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: authorization,
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            });

            res.json(result.data);
        } catch (err) {

            res.status(400).json(err);
        }
    });
}
```

As you see, I'm using multer library to parse formData.

**Note** this function works properly in localhost. but while deploying our App to the firebase hosting, it returns error regarding parsing request.

1. Is it possible to configure firebase to parse formData request? (Using multer or any other library)
2. If is not possible to configure firebase to parse formData request, what is your suggestion? (I mean like don't send request to internal next.js API and make a direct request to servver withot facing CORS error)